# git is ignoring files that aren't in .gitignore?

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

Solved:  Decided to delete the .git directory and try again, since there was nothing in it anyway.  *rm -rf .git*, then *git init*, then *git add .*.  Now it's working, everything is getting added correctly, and things that should be ignored are.  Think I mis-cloned 960gs or html5boilerplate into the project directory instead of a subdirectory.  Thanks everyone for your replies, much appreciated.

---

There are lots of questions on SO about git failing to ignore files specified in .gitignore.  My problem is the exact opposite - git is ignoring files that *aren't* listed in .gitignore.

For example, I've just started a web project using [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/), and am trying to do the initial commit.  However, only a few of the files and directories I need are being staged when I run 'git add *'.

.gitignore in the project directory specifies a list of project, vcs, and other files to ignore, but not *.html, *.xml, *.conf, .htaccess, *.ico, *.png files, which are not being staged to the index.  Strangely, one html file is being added, demo.html, while index.html isn't.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Here's a transcript of the operations for clarity:

```
%> ls -al
total 136
drwxr-xr-x 13 me me  4096 2010-11-08 14:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 me me   720 2010-11-08 13:21 404.html
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  1893 2010-11-08 13:21 apple-touch-icon.png
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:21 build
-rw-r--r--  1 me me   802 2010-11-08 13:21 crossdomain.xml
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:24 css
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:21 demo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me  8920 2010-11-08 13:15 demo.html
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  1150 2010-11-08 13:21 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x  8 me me  4096 2010-11-08 14:04 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 me me   266 2010-11-08 13:44 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  8011 2010-11-08 13:21 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:21 images
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:15 img
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  3115 2010-11-08 13:21 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:21 js
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  5166 2010-11-08 13:21 lighttpd.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  3484 2010-11-08 13:21 mime.types
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  3413 2010-11-08 13:21 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 me me     0 2010-11-08 14:04 output.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  6277 2010-11-08 13:21 README.markdown
-rw-r--r--  1 me me   107 2010-11-08 13:21 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:17 templates
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:21 test
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 2010-11-08 13:45 vim~
-rw-r--r--  1 me me 12274 2010-11-08 13:21 web.config
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 2010-11-08 12:09 wireframes

%> less .gitignore
# Numerous always-ignore extensions
*.diff
*.err
*.orig
*.log
*.rej
*.swo
*.swp
*.vi
*~

# OS or Editor folders
.DS_Store
.cache
.project
.settings
nbproject
thumb.db

# Folders to ignore
.hg
.svn
publish
.idea
templates
template

# files
build/buildinfo.properties

%> git add *
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   css/960.css
#   new file:   css/960_24_col.css
#   new file:   css/reset.css
#   new file:   css/rtl_960.css
#   new file:   css/rtl_960_24_col.css
#   new file:   css/rtl_text.css
#   new file:   css/text.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/960.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/960_24_col.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/demo.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/reset.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/rtl_960.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/rtl_960_24_col.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/rtl_text.css
#   new file:   css/uncompressed/text.css
#   new file:   demo.html
#   new file:   img/12_col.gif
#   new file:   img/16_col.gif
#   new file:   img/24_col.gif
#   new file:   wireframes/basalmiq01.pdf
#   new file:   wireframes/basalmiq01.png
#   new file:   wireframes/basalmiq01.xml
#   new file:   wireframes/fcf_mockingbird.zip
#   new file:   wireframes/fcf_mockingbird_.zip
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   output.txt
```

Comment: Are there any `.gitignore` files in parent directories? What is the contents of `.git/info/exclude`?

Comment: I take it there's a `git status` you clipped out after the `git add`? Is there a .gitignore in a subdirectory? And it's unclear from what you pasted which of the listed files were already tracked and which you expected to be added but weren't. (besides output.txt)

Comment: @Jefromi - I didn't clip anything, that output is verbatim, which is why it's so strange it's missing files that you would think would be included.  And nothing is already tracked, it's a brand new repo and this is the initial commit.

Comment: @unutbu - all lines in <project dir>/.git/info/exclude are commented out, no uncommented directives there.  And there are no .gitignore files in any of the parent directories up to ~/.

Comment: @Kurtosis: I don't think I've *ever* seen `git add` print out the output of git status like that. What version of git are you using?

Comment: @Jef - oh crap you're right, that's the output from git status.

Comment: Ok, to fix it I decided to start over: 'rm -rf .git', then 'git init', then 'git add .'.  Now it's working, everything is getting added correctly, and things that should be ignored are.  No idea what I did the first time around to tangle it up, but fixed now.  Thanks for your replies, much appreciated.

Comment: @Kurtosis: Possibly you managed to put some interesting things in `.git/info/exclude`? That's the only thing in the .git directory actually designed to ignore files.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized; there was clearly some specific thing that happened to the .git directory, and we're not going to figure out exactly what it was!

Comment: That wasn't it, it was just the default exclude file.  I think I know what I did, I must have cloned or fetched html5boilerplate or 960gs from their github pages into the top project directory instead of a subdirectory, so the git repo actually did have already have tracked files in it.  My bad, thanks for helping me think through it.

Comment: Sure, closing is fine.  I'd do it if I could see how.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe those files are already controlled by git.

Comment: It's the initial commit, nothing is in the repo yet.

Comment: Yup. Once git is tracking a file, adding it to `.gitignore` does nothing. You have to tell git to forget about it using `git rm`, or to stop looking for changes to it, using `git update-index --assume-unchanged`